# Where does Stirling series come from?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, factorial

I was reading about Stirling formula and then I saw the famous Stirling series which is as follows:
$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{12n}+\frac{1}{288n^{n}}+...\right)$$
The coefficient used in this series are called **Stirling coefficients**, there exist an explicit formula for 
calculating them which was given by G. Nemes.

The explicit formula is complicated and I prevent of mentioning that, the questions are :

Which one of Stirling series or Stirling formula has been discovered first?

**Can someone explain what is the idea behind defining such a series? where does actually this come 
from?** (This is indeed the most important one, I even can compute the coefficients, but have no idea 
about the notion of Stirling series)

Also Wikipedia says the Stirling formula is in fact the first approximation to the following series, what 
does that mean?how we can reach Stirling formula using this series?

Comment: This comes from the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, thanks, do you have any source to learn about this series? or you don't so can you please explain how Euler-Maclaurin can be used to reach Stirling series?

Comment: For the last question, if n is large, you neglect all but the first term in the series: you end up with Stirling's formula. For a very nice motivational exposition, I recommend the article [Stirling's formula!](http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/452/articles/Stirling.pdf) by N.David Mermin (his earlier "Logarithms!" is also worth reading but I can only find it behind paywalls - both have been reprinted in his wonderful (but somewhat expensive) book [Boojums All the Way Through](https://www.amazon.com/Boojums-All-Way-through-Communicating/dp/0521388805).

Comment: You may find this preprint useful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06689.pdf